# Trimming a mathematical expression

Tags: c#, regex, trim

I've got a Regex: [-]?\d+[-+*^/\d]* and this line of code:

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "[-]?\d+[-+*^/\d]*")){
...
}
```

m.Value = (for example) 2+4*50

Is there any way to get a string array in the form of {"2", "+", "4", "*", "50"}?

Comment: You need a lexer; just write a lexer. They're not hard to write.

Comment: @EricLippert - when the guy involved in designing C# says "not hard to write" how hard could it be :)

Comment: You're going to want a `@` on that regular expression string I think.  But more generally: the regular expression you have and the regular expression you want are very different.

Comment: Let me know when your regex is ready, I'll post examples that break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you've got the wrong regular expression. You have a regex that matches the *entire* string, but you want to split the string on token boundaries, so you want to recognize tokens.

Second, don't attempt to solve the problem of whether `-` is a unary minus or an operator at lex time. That's a parse problem.

Third, you can use ordinary LINQ operators to turn the match collection into an array of strings.

Put it all together:

```
    string s = "10*20+30-40/50";
    var matches = 
      Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+|[-+*/]")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Value)
      .ToArray();
```

This technique only works if your lexical grammar is regular, and many are not. (And even some languages that are *technically* regular are inconvenient to characterize as a regular expression.) As I noted in a comment: writing a lexer is not hard. Consider just writing a lexer rather than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try split on word boundary

```
 var st = "2+4*50";

    var li = Regex.Split(st, @"\b");

    foreach (var i in li)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    2
    +
    4
    *
    50
```